# Flutter UI Guides not showing in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter-plugin

In Android Studio V4.1.3 (build no. Al-201.8743.12.41.7199119) The Flutter UI guides for widgets and methods not showing at all even though it is enabled in the settings. Please, be kind to see the screenshot =>
[no Flutter UI guides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWY0h.png)

I have Flutter Plugin V55.1.1 and Dart Plugin V201.9335 installed.

All your help is highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same android studio version as you and **Flutter** Plugin **V55.1.1** and **Dart** Plugin **V201.9380** installed. Getting the same issue. I have even tried to enable and disable the "Show UI guidelines for build methods" in Setting > Language & Frameworks > Flutter, but nothings work.

I cloned [flutter/sample](https://github.com/flutter/samples) from GitHub and it seem that the UI guides is showing on that samples project.

My current (kinda easy cheat) solution right now is by creating a New Flutter application project via VS Code. And when I open that flutter project on Android studio, the UI guides is there. I have configure my VS Code with the [recommended setting](https://dartcode.org/docs/recommended-settings/) for Dart code.

Tutorial to configure your VS Code reference: https://youtu.be/nAmOt5_fMtU?t=278

I'm pretty new in flutter development but I'm pretty sure there might be something that we can configure on Android Studio seeing that generated project file from VS Code does shows the UI guideline. If someone know how do let me know. Cheers!

Comment: By the way, yesterday, I updated my FLutter SDK to  from V2.0.4 to V2.0.5 and now the UI guidelines are showing :)

Answer (score 1):

You might be creating the new Flutter project and selecting Java for Android. But when you select Kotlin and create project. The issue will be fixed.

And if you want your old projects to be converted to Kotlin, just open the terminal in that project and run this

`run flutter create -a kotlin .`

The dot(.) at the end is also important it will generate the Kotlin files in current directory.

After this, just re-open the project, you'll get the guides.