# How can I enable flutter UI guides in android studio 4.2+

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I have checked the previous questions, some users have got it to work with android studio 3+ but on Android studio 4.2+ it is not working for me.
I have got all the dependencies and settings enabled. as attached in the picture. Could someone please suggest how can I  enable the guide?

android stuio version: 4.2
flutter SDK 2.0.6

Show UI guide for build method is enabled
[image]

How the UI looks in android studio
[image]

Comment: did you tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67118905/flutter-ui-guides-not-showing-in-android-studio)

Comment: yes! I have a more recent version than mentioned there.

Answer (score 0):

Follow each of these steps:

- Go to Help --> Check For Updates and update everthing which comes.
- Go to Tools --> Flutter --> Flutter Upgrade and Flutter Clean.
- Go to File --> Invalidate Caches / Restart.

And Also, check if this issue exists in new projects also.

Let me know if any of these work.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work. Updated everything.